# Product being categorized a certain way causes SQL to print on product page

Tags: magento2

An odd issue I keep running into:

Sometimes when adding a new category to a product, some SQL query prints on the top of the product page. An example:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, 
`stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable` FROM 
`catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN 
`catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON 
cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id='1' AND 
cat_index.visibility IN(3, 2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id='2' INNER 
JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON 
e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND 
stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1 
WHERE (stock_status_index.stock_status = 1) AND (`e`.`entity_id` 
IN('200', '201', '205', '206', '207', '213', '214', '215', '216', 
'219')) ORDER BY FIELD(e.entity_id, ) LIMIT 3
```

This goes away if I take the product out of the category. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

Comment: Check that somewhere in your code query is printed by "echo $collection->getSelect()->__toString();

Comment: I appreciate your response! There are no instances of that anywhere in my code

Comment: It may be written somewhere by using event in other modules but definitely there as per as output is concern. So be cross check in other module also.

Comment: Yeah, I searched the entire project